# How to make a line graph in the unity inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've seen many questions asking how to make a line graph in the unity game-space, but not in the inspector. I wanted to make something sort of like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T51JA.png), but be able to put inputs in from a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for may be satisfied by unity's built in [curveField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.CurveField.html). Theoretically it is meant for animation, but I've seen it used for things like motion profiles and complex interpolations.

What makes it better than a line graph is that it can be edited, either from the editor, or as you wanted, from a script using the `AnimationCurve.AddKey` method (you have to dig out the curve from the curveField)